# setting up a custom domain with a heroku node.js instance

Tags: heroku, dns

I have a node.js app hosted on Heroku, and domain registered with one.com.

I want my one.com DNS to be the domain for my Heroku hosted app - Not just a redirect or an iframe.

What are the correct DNS settings for this?

Comment: Did you checked [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) ?